# 'pip' object expected error: 800a138f

Tags: python, node.js

I'm having some trouble with the 'pip' command in my command tool (Windows). I was hoping to play around with the Wagtail CMS, but upon trying the 'pip install wagtail' this error popped up:

Script:
C:\PATH TO cli.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Object expected
Code: 800a138f
Source Microsoft JScript runtime error

Are there any solutions to this? I have tried 'npm install --reinstall python', and other pip commands but no luck unfortunately.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your PATH variable updated. Go to `C:\Python27\Scripts` in command prompt, and then try `pip` install command. (Python dir may be diff in case of another version)

Comment: Thanks for replying Ashwani. When I try to run the command the path I'm given is C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node-modules\pip\lib\cli.js, which I can't navigate to in the command tool, nor can I find it myself.

Comment: Try running `pip install wagtail` from `C:\Python27\Scripts` using cmd. If you are having trouble changing cmd directory, [check this](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1723&page=3)

Comment: OK so that's done something! it was python34, and has created a load of files. Also, following the Wagtail instructions, have managed to make a site. However, now when using the python manage.py migrate command I'm being told 'python is not  recognized as an internal or external command. I suppose i need to know how to resolve that issue and make the pip command available across my whole comp. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have PATH variable set in Windows Enviroment

1. Open `System Properties` (type it in the start menu, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>)
2. Go to `Advanced system settings` from left-pane
3. Go to `Advanced` tab.
4. Click `Environment Variables`
5. Select `Path` in the `System variables` section
6. Click `Edit`
7. Add python's path to the end of the list (`Variable Value`) (the paths are separated by semicolons). In this case -

   ```
   C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;
   ```

Do not remove or change previous path, Just append these paths at the end. (Separated by `;`)

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much!